# Incorrect Reference Link

Tags: cross-referencing

I have 2 equations. When I use `\ref{}` for the second equation, it gives the correct number but directs to the wrong place. How can I fix this? Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Chapter 16}
\subsection{16.2}
\begin{equation}
\int_{C}f(x,y)ds=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x(t),y(t)\right)\cdot |\vec{r}\,'(t)|\cdot dt
\label{2d}
\end{equation}
\subsection{16.3}
See \ref{2d}
\subsection{16.6}
\begin{equation}
|\vec{r}_x\times \vec{r}_y|=\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2} 
\label{area}
\end{equation}
\subsection{16.7}
See \ref{area}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `latex` twice?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to facilitate the debugging. Sigur suggestion should sort it out!

Comment: Looking at the aux file, both labels refer to equation.16.1, ignoring the subsection number.  Not sure how to fix it yet.

Comment: It's not \theequation, and \subsection definitely calls \refstepcounter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your `\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}` line after `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Apparently there is a conflict between `amsmath` and `hyperref`.

A very similar situation is described here: [Hyperlinking problems when using subequations, hyperref and cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65926/hyperlinking-problems-when-using-subequations-hyperref-and-cleveref)