# Do we have to use starred equations with \tag?

Tags: hyperref, amsmath, tags

Consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \tag{tag}
    1+1=0
\end{equation}
\clearpage
\begin{equation}
    \label{mylabel}
    1+1=3
\end{equation}
Eq~\eqref{mylabel} is on page \pageref{mylabel}.
\end{document}
```

If I compile it with `pdflatex`, the `\pageref` correctly says that the equation (1) is on page 2, however the hyperref points to page 1.

If we change the first `equation` to `equation*`, the hyperref points correctly to page 2.

Note that this change does not alter the `aux`-file, but in the `log`-file the warning

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

disappears.

Hence, my question is: Should one always use starred environments (like `equation*`) for `\tag`ged equations? (I cannot find something related in the documentations of `amsmath` and `hyperref`.)

Comment: I think the short answer is: *yes*. See [Incorrect reference when combining amsmath, hyperref, and \tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210480/82917).

Comment: Thank you for this pointer!