# Index Links To Wrong Page

Tags: indexing

I am using makeidx with \makeindex, hyperref, and documentclass amsbook.  When I view the index, the correct page numbers are listed.  But, when I click on the page number it sends me to the wrong page.  For example, it will say that "finite" is on page 2, which is correct.  But, when I click on "2" it sends me to the second page starting from the title page, not the second page starting from the first page of the book proper.  Here are the pertinent parts of my preamble

```
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=blue}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor=green}

\maketitle
\pagebreak

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}


\tableofcontents
\pagebreak


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the effect of `hypertexnames=false`, because it uses simplified
anchor names. For example page numbers by `\thepage` are replaced by the absolute plain page number. This way, `\thepage` can contain complicate stuff that would break in anchor names, but `\hyperpage` will not work as expected, if there are different page number forms and ranges.

With the default values (`hypertexnames=true` and some other) the page links should work again in the index.