# Page Number on Index Links to Wrong Page

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, indexing

I am facing an issue with indexing and hyperlinks. The page number that shows in the index is correct, but clicking it redirects to the wrong (physical) page on the PDF. I have tried it with multiple PDF viewers as well. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Thesis Name
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{roman}
University Name
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\blindtext[5]

\section{A Long Section}
\blindtext[2]\\

Some Indexed Definition\index{definition!type one}\\

\blindtext[5]\\

Another Indexed Definition\index{definition!type two}\\

\blindtext[4]\\

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The issue is identical to the question posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201758/index-links-to-wrong-page). However the solution doesn't work for me : I have tried using  `\usepackage[hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}`, but the issue persists.

I understand that this is happening because of the two `\pagenumbering{}` commands. Indeed, if I comment them out, both the page number and the physical page it points to work fine. But what baffles me is that the `makeidx` package *knows* the correct page number, and yet it seems `hyperref` doesn't know it!

The same thing happens in the bibliography, with `backref=page` option added to the `hyperref` package (not shown in the MWE).

Any help regarding this is appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the two pages before `\pagenumbering{roman}`. Usually the (internal) frontispiece is numbered like the front matter.

If you insist to start numbering after the “Thesis name”, issue

```
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

at the beginning and restore `\pagestyle{headings}` after `\frontmatter`, which is better than issuing `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{roman}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph}
\pagestyle{empty}

Thesis Name

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{headings}

University Name

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\blindtext[5]

\section{A Long Section}
\blindtext[2]

Some Indexed Definition\index{definition!type one}

\blindtext[5]

Another Indexed Definition\index{definition!type two}

\blindtext[4]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: The template that I am using has `\frontpage`, `\coverpage` etc defined, with `\thispagestyle{empty}` in the definition. I didn't add it to the MWE since I thought that was not the problem!

In any case, I solved the issue by putting `\pagenumbering{roman}` at the very beginning and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` just before `\mainmatter`.